# Minor Downgrade of PostgreSQL from 11.9 to 11.7

Tags: postgresql-11

I have installed the PostgreSQL 11.7 version using yum install on our RHEL 7.7 Development server. Now, when I tried to install PostgreSQL using yum install on our new PRD server, by default, it installed the latest version 11.9. Since the DEV and PRD versions are different, I would like to know below things:

1. Can I downgrade the PostgreSQL 11.9 to 11.7 in the PRD server? If so, what should be the steps I follow? I checked the forums, however, couldn't find any.

If this is not possible, can I uninstall 11.9 and install the PostgreSQL 11.7 version using the yum install? I couldn't find specific steps to perform this.

2. How do I perform the minor upgrade from Postgresql 11.7 to 11.9 ?

Comment: Don't downgrade, _upgrade_ the dev server to 11.9. Your production server defines the version to be used, not the other way round.

Comment: Thanks, This is a new setup and we have not started using the PRD. At this point, we can decide on the version for PRD. Could guide me on how to upgrade the minor version?

Answer (score 0):

> *Can I downgrade the PostgreSQL 11.9 to 11.7 in the PRD server?*

Even if you could, do **not** do it.

Your production server should always be running the latest minor release and your development server should follow that rule.

[Quote from the homepage](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)

> We always recommend that all users run the latest available minor release for whatever major version is in use.

And further:

> For minor releases, the community considers not upgrading to be riskier than upgrading

So just upgrade your dev server to 11.9 and start planing your upgrade for the next minor release in November (which is as simple as shutting down Postgres, installing the new binaries, then starting Postgres again).

Comment: Yea, we decide to upgrade to 11.9. However, could you let me know how to perform this on a RHEL 7.7 as I am not much familiar with PostgreSQL. Thank you.

Comment: The same as any other package in CentOS: `yum upgrade postgresql11` then restart the service: `systemctl restart postgresql-11`